# c# Calling method using P/Invoke causing AccessViolation Exception

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

I interfacing with a device using P/Invoke. But I've come stuck at calling the following method:

```
BOOL __stdcall voGetFirmwareVersion(IN OUT LPTSTR lpVersion,  IN OUT DWORD *dwSize);
```

In my wrapper I have called the method like so:

```
[DllImport(DLL_LOCATION, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern Boolean voGetFirmwareVersion(string s, uint d);
```

I have attempted to change the inputs to Out/Ref and tried adding the [In,Out] attributes but I am constantly getting a AccessViolation Exception.  Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've been at this for a couple of hours now and google hasn't been able to put me straight

Comment: Do you run your program with Admin Permissions?

Comment: Is the libary you're calling unicode? Then Charset.Ansi would be wrong. And the second parameter definitelly needs to be ref.

Comment: try using a `StringBuilder` instead of a `string`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys, I had used string builder before but not with the ref on the second parameter. It is now running but I am getting random Chinese characters. I will keep digging but thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `dwSize` is passed by address, so it should be a `ref` parameter.
- `BOOL` return type must be marshaled if any nonzero value may come as a true value
- I am not sure if you really want to use `Ansi` charset. Try `Auto` or `Unicode`.
- `LPStr` and `StdCall` are not a must, they are the default settings.

So try this:

```
[DllImport(DLL_LOCATION, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool voGetFirmwareVersion([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string s, ref uint d);
```

Comment: Cheers taffer, I got to the answer from Eren and PMF but I am marking this as the my answer due to the explanation.